# How to call a controller method from middleware and only allow this method to be called from this middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a Controller, which has 2 functions and a middleware.

My middleware

```
try
{
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    if (/* some logic here */)
    {
        await _next(httpContext);

        // Some logic here
        var someReturnValue = someFunction();

        // Need to call the Controller Method here
        // call SaveStaging(someReturnValue);
    }
    else
    {
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

In my Controller

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "APIKeyAuthentication")]
[LogAction]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResult>> PostData([FromBody] DataObj request)
    {
        ServiceResult result = new ServiceResult();
        result.isSuccessful = true;
        return Ok(result);
    }

    public async Task SaveStaging(int logNumber)
    {

    }
}
```

So, initially, user will call the PostData endpoint. In this method, it will return that it accepts the data posted by user.
Then in the middleware, I will need to do some things, and finally, I would like to call the `SaveStaging` method in the Controller. I want this `SaveStaging` method to be only accessible for the middleware, and should not be called directly by the user.

So my question:

1. How to call this method from the middleware?
2. How to limit `SaveStaging` to be accessible only to the middleware?

Comment: Why is SaveStaging in the controller then?

Comment: Because I want to avoid having too many logic in the middleware. I want the logic pertaining to this controller action to be in the controller file.

Comment: Why not use the [`OnActionExecuted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted?view=aspnetcore-3.0) method in the controller then, or an [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Comment: How I know which method was called from OnActionExecuted ? Also, I need to pass some id from the middleware to the method in the controller

Answer (score 2):

You should consider wrapping `SaveStaging` into a service because it appears to be a cross-cutting concern. Beyond that, it's likely wise to implement a layered architecture as a matter of refactoring.

Since this is .NET Core, I would recommend fully embracing [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) and injecting the service into your middleware.

```cs
public interface IStagingService 
{
    Task Save(int logNumber);
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStagingService _service;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MyController(IStagingService service, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
        _accessor = accessor  ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessor));;
    }
    //....
}

public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IStagingService _service;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IStagingService service)
    {
        _next = next;
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
    // ...
}
```

In the beginning, your service's will likely start out small and simple. In the event the app grows, the complexity of this layer will likely increase, spawning the need for some [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) services (i.e. services composed of services) and maybe some providers for thing like data access.